# Enforcing logical models boundary in large Ruby on Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have a Ruby on Rails application that is getting quite big.  And we are trying to split it up into separate logical domains, and we are wondering how to enforce that the logical domain is not crossed.

Let's say we have models A, B, C, D.  Model A, B are used in one part of the app, Model C, D in another.  We would like to be able to draw some logical system boundaries, for the sake of faster continuous integration and independent teams.

We can re-organize the code, and break some dependencies.

For example,
let's say model B is a join or mapping table, that joins A and C in a many-to-many relationships

```
class A
  has_many :C, through: B
```

We could change this to:

```
class A
  has_many :B
```

From A, you get a list of c_id through the mapping table B, and then you can call a GET API on C, to get the list of C objects.  This is similar to if we were to A and C physically in separate databases, and we want to display a list of C objects, when we show A.

Eventually, we would probably want A, B in one service, and C be in a separate service.   In the meanwhile, we do want to keep A, B, C are in the same Postgres database, but just make a logical extraction.

**Question:** What are ways we can enforce logical system boundary in Rails + Postgres, so that we don't have team members that take class A, and accidentally joins with C, and introduce unintended coupling before we do a full service split.

This blog suggests using test suites and selectively loading the  necessary dependencies https://medium.com/@dan_manges/the-modular-monolith-rails-architecture-fb1023826fc4.  But I feel that might not prevent developer from using SQL directly to join tables across logical boundary. I am wondering what others might have tried.

Comment: You can not stop someone from handwriting SQL to join A to C and really you can't stop them from ORM relating A to C using rails convenience methods. You can however place A and B in one Module and C in a different Module this will at least make the second issue a more intentional circumvention of the artificial boundaries you have laid down. The only way for you to truly decouple C from A is to abstract it into a service that lives in its own database.